# How to use socket.io in a controller

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io

i am try to get all user list when user login with my app.

```
//example code which i want
router.post('/log',loging)
exports.login= (req,res){
if(email and password matched){
//also pushed user in array
io.emit('users',array)
}else{
//just returning message to client

 }
}
```

please guide me.

Comment: Use a middleware! @ADEEL

Answer (score 0):

I can think of 2 options :

### A. Use `app.set`

For `Express 5.x` you can use `app.set` and `app.get` to attach stuff to your server instance . Like this : http://expressjs.com/en/5x/api.html#app.set

```js
// where you setup your webserver and socket.io instance 
app.set('io', io);
```

```js
// in your controller
function (req, res) {
  req.app.io.emit('users', array);
}
```

### B. Export `io` instance from module

Outsource your `io` instance creation into another file and export from there. It will always give you the same instance.

```js
//io-setup.js
const io = require('socket.io').listen(server);

module.exports = io;
```

```js
// in your controller
const io = require('./io-setup.js');

function (req, res) {
  io.emit('users', array);
}
```